# dynamically create title, child, subchild elements in array from a array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to achieve result where the title, child, subchild and therefore gets match and create a new array as shown below.

how can we add this data into table showing title, child, subchild as shown in the picture[image]

here i'm facing the issue that the project structure is dynamic and can have n number of files, folders, subfolders etc.
any suggestions on this problem?.

```
let a = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "public",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "public",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "src",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "assests",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/assests",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "components",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/components",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "store",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/store",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "modules",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/store/modules",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "notification",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/store/modules/notification",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "projectDetails",
      "type": "tree",
      "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails",
      "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "LICENSE",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "LICENSE",
      "mode": "100644",
      "licenseData": [
          "GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE",
          "Version 3, 19 November 2007",
          "",
          "Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. &lt;https:&#x2F;&#x2F;fsf.org&#x2F;&gt;"
      ]
  },
  {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "README.md",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "README.md",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "11",
      "name": "babel.config.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "babel.config.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "12",
      "name": "jsconfig.json",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "jsconfig.json",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "13",
      "name": "package-lock.json",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "package-lock.json",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "14",
      "name": "package.json",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "package.json",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "15",
      "name": "favicon.ico",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "public/favicon.ico",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "index.html",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "public/index.html",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "publiccode.yml",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "publiccode.yml",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "18",
      "name": "App.vue",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/App.vue",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "logo.png",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/assests/logo.png",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "20",
      "name": "dashboard.vue",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/components/dashboard.vue",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "21",
      "name": "home.vue",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/components/home.vue",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "22",
      "name": "main.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/main.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "index.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/index.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "24",
      "name": "action.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/notification/action.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "25",
      "name": "getters.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/notification/getters.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "26",
      "name": "index.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/notification/index.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "27",
      "name": "mutation.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/notification/mutation.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "28",
      "name": "action.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/action.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "29",
      "name": "getters.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/getters.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "30",
      "name": "index.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/index.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "31",
      "name": "mutation.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/mutation.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
      "id": "32",
      "name": "vue.config.js",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "vue.config.js",
      "mode": "100644"
  }
]
```

Comment: I have removed the vuejs3 tag, since you accepted a jQuery solution, so I assume the tag was just a mistake. If you are indeed using Vue, you should not mix it with jQuery, but ask for a solution in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$.each(a, function() {
  var item = this;
  var isRoot = item.path.indexOf("/") == -1;
  if (isRoot) {
    $("#tree").append(`<li data-path="${item.path}">${item.name}</li>`);
  } else {
    let splicedStr = item.path.substring(0, item.path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var target = $("#tree").find(`li[data-path='${splicedStr}']`);
    if (target) {
      if (target.find("ul").length == 0)
        target.append("<ul></ul>")

      $("ul", target).append(`<li data-path="${item.path}">${item.name}</li>`);
    }
  }
})
```

This will loop over each item in your array, and insert it in the ul, depending on the item's path.

Note this is not bullet proof and is depending on the order of your array, but it should give you a good start.

**Demo**

```js
let a = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "public",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "public",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "src",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "assests",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/assests",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "components",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/components",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "store",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/store",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "6",
    "name": "modules",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/store/modules",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "notification",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/store/modules/notification",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "projectDetails",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "9",
    "name": "LICENSE",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "LICENSE",
    "mode": "100644",
    "licenseData": [
      "GNU AFFERO GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE",
      "Version 3, 19 November 2007",
      "",
      "Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc. &lt;https:&#x2F;&#x2F;fsf.org&#x2F;&gt;"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "10",
    "name": "README.md",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "README.md",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "babel.config.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "babel.config.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "12",
    "name": "jsconfig.json",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "jsconfig.json",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "13",
    "name": "package-lock.json",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "package-lock.json",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "14",
    "name": "package.json",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "package.json",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "15",
    "name": "favicon.ico",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "public/favicon.ico",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "16",
    "name": "index.html",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "public/index.html",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "17",
    "name": "publiccode.yml",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "publiccode.yml",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "18",
    "name": "App.vue",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/App.vue",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "19",
    "name": "logo.png",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/assests/logo.png",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "20",
    "name": "dashboard.vue",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/components/dashboard.vue",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "21",
    "name": "home.vue",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/components/home.vue",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "22",
    "name": "main.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/main.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "23",
    "name": "index.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/index.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "24",
    "name": "action.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/notification/action.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "25",
    "name": "getters.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/notification/getters.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "26",
    "name": "index.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/notification/index.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "27",
    "name": "mutation.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/notification/mutation.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "action.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/action.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "29",
    "name": "getters.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/getters.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "name": "index.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/index.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "31",
    "name": "mutation.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "src/store/modules/projectDetails/mutation.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  },
  {
    "id": "32",
    "name": "vue.config.js",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "vue.config.js",
    "mode": "100644"
  }
]

$.each(a, function() {
  var item = this;
  var isRoot = item.path.indexOf("/") == -1;
  if (isRoot) {
    $("#tree").append(`<li data-path="${item.path}">${item.name}</li>`);
  } else {
    let splicedStr = item.path.substring(0, item.path.lastIndexOf("/"));
    var target = $("#tree").find(`li[data-path='${splicedStr}']`);
    if (target) {
      if (target.find("ul").length == 0)
        target.append("<ul></ul>")

      $("ul", target).append(`<li data-path="${item.path}">${item.name}</li>`);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tree"></ul>
```